# how to take out variable from $.getJson function and use it

Tags: jquery, geojson

I'm trying to read a .geoJson file that will add some points to a map. 
my data file lookes like this:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "start": "1970", "end": "1972" },"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 11.924550479340329, 55.94619451008279 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "start": "1975", "end": "1976" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.06219628503271, 55.909617190392566 ] } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "start": "1979", "end": "1980" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.06219628503271, 55.909617190392566 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "start": "1980", "end": "1985" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.284822339303718, 55.639778377234506 ] } }
]
};
```

so this is the data.geojson.

as you can see there are start date and end date  and i need to use this to put it in a timeline else i would just have used addTo(map) and all the points will be there.

but my code to call my file is:

```
var points = null;
$.getJSON("data.geojson", function(data) {
points = L.geoJson(data);
});
```

to try and test  if the code works I did a "points.addTo(map);"  and it all went blank on my screen, I'm sure my data works because when i write the code like this:

```
$.getJSON("data.geojson", function(data) {
points = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
});
```

I can see all the points. But by doing this I can't use my data for the right purpose. 
Hope some one can help me with this problem.

Comment: In your first example, how and when are you calling `addTo(map)`? This feels like an async issue.

Comment: in the first one i need  the points for something later where i add it to map 
like `var pointsToTimeline = L.timeline(points);` 
       `pointsToTimeline.addTo(map) ;`
but this do not work

Comment: This might be the issue.. can't tell without an MVCE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using d3.json to import my data and use it for the purpose i wanted, and it turned out to be the async problem. 
By inporting the d3 loading option:

`d3.select(window).on("load", init)`

And then use this code to load the file:

`d3.json("data.geojson", function(data) {`
`console.log(data);`
 `console.log(data[0]);`
 `points = data;`

And then all my coordinats got linked to the timeline.